# how can I avoid time out in django

Tags: django, django-celery

I am creating a site that downloads videos from other sites and converts them to GIF when requested.

The problem is that it takes too long to download and convert videos.

This causes a 504 timeout error.
How can I avoid timeout?
Currently, I am downloading using celery when we receive a request.
While downloading, django redirects right away.

```py
def post(self, request):
        form = URLform(request.POST)
        ctx = {'form':form}
        ....
        t = downloand_video.delay(data)
        return redirect('gif_to_mp4:home')
```

This prevents transferring the files to the user.
Because celery cannot return file to user or response.

How can I send the file to the user?

Comment: maybe `await` before `return`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
Use channel